# match two columns in Dataframe and if matched return the corresponding third column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe which looks as follows

```
    First name  Last name   Position
0   Troy          Hudson    NaN
1   NaN            NaN      NaN
```

I have input variable

```
x = input("first name ")
y = input("last name")

lo1 = x.lower()
lo2 = y.lower()
```

I have tried

```
match = df[df['First name'].str.match('Troy', na=False)]
```

to match first name and return an entire row.

I want to convert the first name and last name in the Dataframe to lowercase and if first, last name matches with my input lo1 and lo2 I want to return the corresponding position in lowercase. If position = NaN then print not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be pretty straightforward

```py
first_names = df['First name'].str.lower()
last_names = df['Last name'].str.lower()
match = (first_names == lo1) & (last_names == lo2)
position = df['Position'][match].dropna()

if len(position) == 0:
    print('Not Found')
else:
    print(position)
```